# Concat Angular 2 routes

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

Is there a way to concatenate two routes array in Angular 2? I need to split route definitions into different files so I have multiple variables which I want to merge.
I've tried using array push but with no luck.

i.e (this is working):

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Home'
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'page1',
        loadChildren: './page1/page1.module#Page1Module'
      }
    ]
  }
];

function getRoutes(){
  return routes;
};


@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
```

but this is not working (I get a "cannot find Page 1 module" error when I navigate to /page1).

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Home'
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
      }
    ]
  }
];

function getRoutes(){
  // Actually customRoutes will be splited in its own file and imported
  let customRoutes = {
    path: 'page1',
    loadChildren: './page1/page1.module#Page1Module'
  }

  routes[1].children.push(customRoutes)
  return routes;
};


@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please clearify. Is the first simple example without the merge even not working?

Comment: You're not using the function `getRoutes()` in `RouterModule.forRoot(routes)`.

Comment: Yes sorry, should be `RouterModule.forRoot(getRoutes())`, but I can't edit my answer. `function getRoutes()` should also be `export function getRoutes()`. The first example is working, the second is not working.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this anyhow? I need to concat my routes, too.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new variable.

```
function getRoutes(){
  // Let's make this an array
  let customRoutes: Routes = [{
    path: 'page1',
    loadChildren: './page1/page1.module#Page1Module'
  }]
  var allRoutes: Routes = []; // Push all routes into this
  routes.forEach(r => allRoutes.push(r));
  // Even better would be to do this with a condition in the forEach instead of hardcoding the index
  allRoutes[1].children.push(customRoutes);
  // allRoutes.push(otherCustomRoutes);
  return allRoutes;
};

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(getRoutes()) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
```

I am using Angular 8, so maybe this didn't work in the past?